# Is it Swipe method supporting in android appium version 1.3.4?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, swipe, appium

I have tried with implementing swipe method for android devices,but this method not working in Appium 1.3.4 version.
Below the code I have wrote:

```
public void swipe() {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    HashMap < String, Double > swipeObject = new HashMap < String, Double > ();
    swipeObject.put("startX", 0.95);
    swipeObject.put("startY", 0.5);
    swipeObject.put("endX", 0.05);
    swipeObject.put("endY", 0.5);
    swipeObject.put("duration", 1.0);
    js.executeScript("emulator: swipe", swipeObject);
}
```

And call the `swipe()` in required place in that same class.
It throws error message like this:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please
>   help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did
>   not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 7
>   milliseconds

Please anyone help me on this issue.
Thanks

Comment: the same problem I have in iOS. I asked in appium github, [this](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4415)  was their answer, which didn't help me at all...

Comment: @User : do we have an accepted answer listed down here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question your wrote for iOS, I understand that you write your tests in Java.

If that is the case, try to check what version of the **appium java-client** you are using (check what you have in maven dependencies if you are using maven?)

The latest appium java-client (2.1.0) release should have support exactly for what you are looking for: swipe on element, as described here:

https://discuss.appium.io/t/java-client-2-1-0-released/1462

I think this is also what the Appium guys were trying to suggest with their answer regarding your iOS question.